# как на random расставить фигуры в шахматах javascript

Tags: javascript

есть вот такой код и я хочу сделать так чтобы при нажатий на button   фигуры расставлялись random, как это сделать ?

```
html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="left">
            <div id="field"></div>
        </div>
        <button>run</button>
    </div> 

    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


javascript:

let chess = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];

function Draw() {
    let out = '';
    let m = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < chess.length; i++) {
        for(let k = 0; k < chess.length; k++) {
            if(m % 2 == 0) {
                out += `<div class="chess-block" data-x="${k}" data-y="${i}"></div>`;
            }else {
                out += `<div class="chess-block bg-black" data-x="${k}" data-y="${i}"></div>`;
            }
            m++;
        }
        m++;
    }
    document.querySelector('#field').innerHTML = out;
    document.querySelectorAll('.chess-block').forEach(function(element) {
        element.onclick = queen;
    });
}

Draw();

function queen() {
    let x = this.dataset.x;
    let y = this.dataset.y;
    console.log(x + " " + y);
}
```

Comment: Семь фигуры коня?! `=_-"` А как это понимать?)

Comment: ну ладно , например любое количество фигур

Comment: взять очередную фигуру, выбрать случайно столбец и строку, поставить в него фигуру, если там не занято. повторять поиск пока не будет найдено свободное место. повторять пока не кончатся фигуры для расстановки.